# Nested loop in x86 Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

Maybe this is stupid, but I'm pretty new to assembler, so please bear with me.

Is there any way to implement nested loops in assembler?
An example would be much appreciated

I created this simple code out of an example, it outputs the letters: WVUTSR I modified it a bit in order to output it like this:

```
W
VW
UVW
TUVW
STUVW
RSTUVW
```

But instead, I get this:

```
WW
VV
UU
TT
SS
RR
```

Here's the code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

M DB 'W'

.CODE

MAIN PROC FAR
MOV AX, @DATA
MOV DS, AX
MOV AX, 003H
INT 10H

; for (CX = 6; CX != 0; CX--) { // PSEUDO CODE
    ; for (BL = 0; BL != 7-CX; BL++) {
        ; putchar(M+BL);
    ; }
    ; M--;
    ; putchar(10);
    ; putchar(13);
; }

MOV CX, 6
OUTER:
INNER:
MOV AL, 7
SUB AL, CL
CMP BL, AL
JE INNEREQUAL
MOV AH, 02
MOV DL, M
INT 21H
MOV DL, AL
INT 21H
INC BL
JNE INNER

INNEREQUAL:
DEC M

MOV AH, 2
MOV DL, 10
INT 21H
MOV DL, 13
INT 21H
LOOP OUTER

MOV AH, 4CH
INT 21H

MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

I'm using tasm if that helps. I'm about to pull my hair right now too.

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: Following up Oli's advice: The debugger will let you step through the program one instruction at a time.  Pay *extremely* close attention to what happens to memory and the registers on each step; check the instruction definitions.  If you do this, your problem will become apparant.